# htaccess 404 all hosts not matching my host

Tags: .htaccess

Someone has pointed a host towards my site, I would like to 404 any requests coming from any host that is not my host, how can I do that with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a top rule like this in your site root .htaccess or Apache config files:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will return more appropriate `403` (forbidden) error to any request that doesn't `example.com` or `www.example.com` in request.

Change `example.com` to your actual host name.